# Prototype-binding on re-evaluated anonymous constructor retroactive to original instantiated objects

Tags: javascript, oop

This is more of a theory question than a how-to question.  I was working on a project in which objects can "differentiate" into several different types, so I decided to explore some of Javascript's dynamic features, but there's one thing that has me really confused:

```
OriginalConstructor = function() {this.value = 42;}
originalInstance = new OriginalConstructor();
ModifiedConstructor = eval(originalInstance.constructor);
ModifiedConstructor.prototype.addedFunction = function(x) {return this.value + x;}
modifiedInstance = new ModifiedConstructor();
document.write("modified: " + modifiedInstance.addedFunction(10));
document.write("<br>original: " + originalInstance.addedFunction(20));
```

Why is `addedFunction` bound to `originalInstance`, even though `ModifiedConstructor` was copied through `eval()`?  Surely these two constructors can't have the same reference, can they?

Is there a way to modify an object (or future instances) without affecting other objects already instantiated from the same constructor?  I know there are other ways to approach this, but I want to understand Javascript at a deeper level.  Thanks for any insights you can offer.

@Felix Kling:
Thanks for the quick, clear and complete answer.  For some reason, I thought the constructor property was a string that could be parsed by eval(), so now I understand why this didn't work.  I still don't fully understand prototypal inheritance, but at least now I know what I need to study.  Thank you!

EDIT:
I get it now.  Prototypal inheritance seems pretty weird if you're coming from a background in classical OOP, but it's conceptually simpler and easier to understand, AND it's actually more powerful in some ways.  If you want to learn more about Javascript's prototypal inheritance, I highly recommend these articles:

http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

http://www.laktek.com/2011/02/02/understanding-prototypical-inheritance-in-javascript/

http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/how-prototypal-inheritance-really-works.html

http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance

Also, if you need this kind of flexibility, you may want to consider using an "entity system", which would offer several advantages as an alternative to a complex hierarchy of inheritance.  Most articles about entity systems focus on game development, but I think this architecture could be useful for other applications as well.  It's a very foreign concept to OOP programmers, so set aside everything you know about OOP and think more in terms of relational database design.  Check it out:

http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ModifiedConstructor` **is not** a copy of `OriginalConstructor`, it is one and the same function.

The first instruction in [`eval`'s algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.1) is:

> If Type(*x*) is not String, return *x*.

i.e. you simply get back what you pass in. `OriginalConstructor === ModifiedConstructor` yields `true`.

> Is there a way to modify an object (or future instances) without affecting other objects already instantiated from the same constructor?

You can, through prototypal inheritance:

```
ModifiedConstructor = function() {
    OriginalConstructor.apply(this, arguments);
};

ModifiedConstructor.prototype = Object.create(OriginalConstructor.prototype);
ModifiedConstructor.prototype.constructor = ModifiedConstructor;
```

Now you can add functions to `ModifiedConstructor.prototype` without affecting instances created by `OriginalConstructor`.

If you only want to prevent already created instances from being extended, you could just overwrite `OriginalConstructor.prototype`, but is not a clean solution and will also break `instanceOf` for the existing instances.